# How to send a multipart/mixed HTTP POST request through Fitnesse?

Tags: fitnesse

I want to send a HTTP POST request with **Content-Type : Multipart/mixed** using **FitNesse**  .
I need a solution only using Fitnesse Tool http://fitnesse.org/ as it is required for my project.
Any help/guidance would be great.

Answer (score 1):

FitNesse itself cannot do what you want.  You will need a fixture that does the work of the multipart upload.

You can take a look at https://github.com/smartrics/RestFixture/wiki and see if it matches your needs.

If not, you will have to write your own fixture class. HttpClient is a pretty powerful and usable class to build something like this with. Unfortunately, I cannot provide a working example as a reference.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I am testing a HTTP request with content-type as application/xml and I am using the same fixture classes

Answer (score 1):

Just wrote a fitnesse fixture for multipart mixed content types.
The already existing smartrics rest fixtures `can handle only multipart/form-data  NOT multipart/mixed`.

It is also strange that the Httpcomponent 3.2  does not support multipart/mixed, but only multipart/form-data. Worse enough, I see no documentation that it does not support multipart/mixed. It is only on going through the source code, that I could see that the 'multipart/form-data' content type is hard-coded all over the place.

My fixture is written using :

- `Http component 4.3 : I have added additional support for multipart/mixed, apart from the already existing multipart/form-data`.
- `Smartrics rest fixutre 3.0 : Extended the already existing restfixture class and the partfactory class to support multipart/mixed`.

Download the fixture from :
https://code.google.com/p/multipart-rest-fitnesse-fixture/

Sample fitnesse Request to illustrate the usage:
http://geekoolympics.blogspot.in/2014/01/multipart-fitnesse-fixture-for-restful.html